# Blazor .NET8.0 OnAfterRenderAsync never fired

Tags: blazor, .net-8.0

I'm trying to implement Google reCaptcha in a Blazor server side app, but OnAfterRenderAsync is never called.

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
      await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<int>("googleRecaptcha", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this), "google_recaptcha", "site_key");
    }
    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
}
```

I'm trying to implement what reported [here](https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/blazor/javascipt-interop/how-do-i-implement-google-recaptcha-in-a-blazor-webassembly-application)

Comment: Specify your @rendermode and application type.

Comment: It' a Blazor Web App working in InteractiveServer mode

Comment: if `OnAfterRenderAsync`is not called then you are statically rendering the page and have no `Interactivity` set .